# Does webrender in emacs.ng not work on MacOS

Tags: osx

I am trying out emacs.ng and I am specifically looking to render graphics (webpage) images in emacs.  So, I wanted to try webrender.

However, after `./config --with-webrender` I get errors due to conflicts between nsgui and wrgui when building emacs.

I've tried wrapping the code which is `ifdef HAVE_NS` in `ifndef USE_WEBRENDER`, but I feel like I might be chasing a rabbit down the hole.

So, has anyone else been down this path.  Am I likely to eventually get a working solution or is MacOS intimately bound with ns (nextstep?) as its rendering engine?

Comment: For the curious, you can read more about emacs-ng at https://emacs-ng.github.io/emacs-ng/ .